# Xcode 5 not recognizing custom Font

Tags: iphone, fonts, ios7, xcode5

I have **Xcode 5.0.1** and I am developing for **iOS 7**.

I have a custom font file named **Roboto-Regular.ttf** and it is working perfectly in **xcode 4.6.3** but when I add it in **xcode 5.0.1** it does not work.

I cannot even preview the **ttf** file in xcode 5 where as I can preview it in xcode 4.6.

I have tried cleaning my project, restarting xcode 5, restarting mac but no luck.

Any ideas what could be the problem here??

**Edited**

The ttf Files are present in my "Copy Bundle Resources" list and I have also added the array "Fonts provided by application" in my projectName-info.plist with ttf extension e.g "Item 0 :  Roboto-Regular.ttf".

An another thing bugging me is why is the xcode 5 not showing the preview of these font files!!!

Comment: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your .ttf file present inside the copy bundle respurces!
[image]

also please check .plist file array and font and file name once.[image]

and use below code:

[YOURLable setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontname size:15.0]];

Comment: yes I added this already in .plist after Om Prakash's answer.
This is my line of code:  
self.lbTitleHeading.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:30];

Comment: have you tried with other font .ttf file except the Roboto-Light ?

Comment: yes, I've tried 3 different files(Thin, light, Regular). And all of these files are working fine in xcode 4.6.3 .

Comment: You can find font names for iOS here: http://iosfonts.com/ also i think problem in .ttf file because are you not able to get the preview of file.

Comment: The same .ttf files are working fine in Xcode 4.6. I think there is something wrong with xcode 5

Answer (score 1):

Add your font className in Fonts provided by application array in Plist.

and set fontName with font Class name.
[lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:15]];

its work on Xcode5.0.1.. :)

Comment: just tried this, still no luck :(.
And I still cannot see the preview of ttf files in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

(Solved in Xcode5)

First, have patience and go through this [link](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) and recheck the points

Then, along with adding 'Fonts provided by application' in the Plist file, also add the same fonts with extension in 'Project Name' > Info Tab and save.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Note : Use stable version of Xcode 5.1.1 instead of Xcode 5.0.1 (which is in beta).
```

You can create custom font in Xcode 5.1.1 using following steps :

1. Import font type into your project (*.ttf file)
2. Add **“Fonts provided by application”** key into plist of your project.
3. Add custom font as an item array in **“Fonts provided by application”** key.
4. Now, you can use font in label as :

   [lblName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@“CustomFontName”  size:14.0]];